# Text output from html document to php form

Tags: php, html, text, output

I want separate html-documents to use the same php-file for the email-functionality. Therefore I need to import some plain text from the relevant html-document and into the php-form.

With this code..:

```
    $email_message = "Thank you for your request on $htmltextid .\n\n";
```

..it's no problem to include outputs from the text-fields to the email:

```
<input name="htmltextid" id="htmltextid" type="text" placeholder="Some text" />
```

But when I try to include some text outside the text-fields, the result is some empty space in the email:

```
<H1 id="htmltextid">flying pigs</H1>
```

I've tried similar with "p" and "span" too.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: within FORMs only FORM-ELEMENTs (input,textarea) collecting data ,  maybe you can use INPUT type=hidden to collect other data

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to s.d.a.p.e I found the solution.

With the type="hidden" command I could use a text-field as output and let it be invisible. But the field needed to be prefilled to be included in the mail, so I used value="Some text" to prefill it:

```
<input name="htmltextid" id="htmltextid" type="hidden" value="flying pigs"/>
```